# Add a query which checks if value is present in field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have the following query

```
{  
 "query":{  
  "bool":{  
     "must":[  
        {  
           "match":{  
              "fieldOne":{  
                 "query":"One two three four five six",
                 "minimum_should_match":2
              }
           }
        },
        {  
           "match":{  
              "fieldTwo":{  
                 "query":"ten eleven twelve",
                 "minimum_should_match":2
              }
           }
        }
     ]
  }
}
}
```

what I wanted to add is that fieldOne must contain the value 'seven'. I tried adding another query as follows which does not return any results

```
        {  
           "match":{  
              "fieldOne":{  
                 "query":"seven"
              }
           }
        },
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**: Added mapping and sample data

Mapping is as follows:

```
{
  "dataindex": {
"mappings": {
  "data": {
    "properties": {
      "fieldOne": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "fieldTwo": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "fieldThree": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Sample data with two documents

```
  {
    "_index": "dataindex",
    "_type": "data",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 55.47536,
    "_source": {
      "id": "ae5836",
      "fieldOne": "One two three four five six",
      "fieldTwo": "ten eleven twelve",
      "fieldThree": blah,
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "dataindex",
    "_type": "data",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 55.47536,
    "_source": {
      "id": "ae5836",
      "fieldOne": "One two three four five six seven",
      "fieldTwo": "ten eleven twelve",
      "fieldThree": blah,
    }
  }
```

I am using this document as a proof of concept hence the simple data

Comment: Can you add your index mapping and sample data you've in your index?

Comment: I have added mapping and some data

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
{  
 "query":{  
  "bool":{  
     "must":[  
        {  
           "match":{  
              "fieldTwo":{  
                 "query":"ten eleven twelve",
                 "minimum_should_match":2
              }
           }
        },
        {  
           "bool":{  
              "must":[  
                 {  
                    "match":{  
                       "fieldOne":{  
                          "query":"One two three four five six",
                          "minimum_should_match":3
                       }
                    }
                 },
                 {  
                    "match":{  
                       "fieldOne":{  
                          "query":"seven",
                          "minimum_should_match":1
                       }
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     ]
  }
}
}
```